# Refreshing a tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

Code:

```
import tkinter, urllib.request, json, io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
main = tkinter.Tk()
main.geometry('500x500+800+300')
dogapi = urllib.request.urlopen(f'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
dogjson = dogapi.read()
dogdict = json.loads(dogjson)
url=dogdict['message']
m = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
mp = io.BytesIO(m.read())
mpi = Image.open(mp)
tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(mpi)
l = tkinter.Label(main, image=tkimg)
b = tkinter.Button(main, text='Next Dog', command='do something to refresh the dog photo')
l.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

I have this code that gets a random dog photo and loads it in to a window, as well as a button.
This works fine but the "Next Dog" button doesn't actually do anything, and the dog photo almost never matches up with the window. How could I add functionality to the button, and make the dog photo size consistent?

Comment: You'd need a function that changes the dog photo that is displayed. then have the button call that function using lambda: functionname()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the fetching of the dog image in a function and update the image of the label inside the function.  Then assign this function to the `command` option of the button.

```py
import tkinter, urllib.request, json, io
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

main = tkinter.Tk()
main.geometry('500x500+800+300')

# maximum size of image
W, H = 500, 460

# resize image but keeping the aspect ratio
def resize_image(img):
    ratio = min(W/img.width, H/img.height)
    return img.resize((int(img.width*ratio), int(img.height*ratio)), Image.ANTIALIAS)

def fetch_image():
    dogapi = urllib.request.urlopen(f'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random')
    dogjson = dogapi.read()
    dogdict = json.loads(dogjson)
    url = dogdict['message']
    m = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    mpi = resize_image(Image.open(m))
    tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(mpi)
    l.config(image=tkimg) # show the image
    l.image = tkimg # save a reference of the image to avoid garbage collection

# label to show the image
l = tkinter.Label(main, image=tkinter.PhotoImage(), width=W, height=H)
b = tkinter.Button(main, text='Next Dog', command=fetch_image)

l.pack()
b.pack()

fetch_image() # fetch first image
main.mainloop()
```